# Using JOIN Within Case DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, vba, db2

so I am experimenting with CASE to try and generate a report and I am stuck.

What I am trying to do is take a list of items (ITEM) and add information from other tables to it. If there is a value in a certain column, then the price needs to be pulled from another table (PRICE); otherwise, it needs to use the price already on ITEM. I have tried numerous variations to no avail, but this is the latest:

```
sqlStr = "SELECT i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT Item, i.INAME Description1, i.INAME2 Description2, i.IUNITS UM, " _
       & "i.IPRCCD PClass, i.ICSTCD CClass, i.IPACCD Pack, " _
       & "CASE " _
            & "WHEN (i.IPRCCD != '') THEN (SELECT p.$LIST FROM DB.PRICE p " _
                                                    & "LEFT JOIN DB.ITEM i " _
                                                    & "ON p.$PRCCD = i.IPRCCD) " _
            & "ELSE (i.ILIST) "_
            & "END AS PRICE " _
       & "FROM DB.ITEM i " _
       & "WHERE (i.IMFGR = '" & man & "')  " _
       & "ORDER BY i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT"
```

Comment: does your column IPRCCD have NULLs then you also need to use when (i.IPRCCD is not null and i.iprccd !='')

Comment: Gave that a try too and I still get an ODBC error. Run-time error '1004'.

Comment: Can you post sample data for the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subselect

```
(SELECT p.$LIST FROM DB.PRICE p 
LEFT JOIN DB.ITEM i 
ON p.$PRCCD = i.IPRCCD)
```

returns all rows from the table `DB.PRICE` -- obviously, it cannot be assigned where a single value is expected. Apparently, your intent was to correlate that subselect to the outer select:

```
(SELECT p.$LIST FROM DB.PRICE p 
WHERE p.$PRCCD = i.IPRCCD)
```

assuming that returns a single record for each `i.IPRCCD`. A better way of doing this though is to avoid the subselect altogether:

```
"SELECT i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT Item, i.INAME Description1, i.INAME2 Description2, i.IUNITS UM, " _
   & "i.IPRCCD PClass, i.ICSTCD CClass, i.IPACCD Pack, " _
   & "CASE " _
        & "WHEN (i.IPRCCD != '') THEN (p.$LIST) " _ 
        & "ELSE (i.ILIST) "_
        & "END AS PRICE " _
   & "FROM DB.ITEM i " _
   & "LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.PRICE p " _
   & "ON p.$PRCCD = i.IPRCCD " _
   & "WHERE (i.IMFGR = '" & man & "')  " _
   & "ORDER BY i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT"
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried your last suggestion first and it does exactly what I am after. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this to get regional pricing. Have you considered doing your join in the main part instead? It would avoid checking the DB.ITEM table twice. This is off the top of my head and untested. I stripped it down to just the SQL statement and reformatted it for my own readability, so make sure to adapt back to your own needs.

```
SELECT i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT Item
    ,i.INAME Description1
    ,i.INAME2 Description2
    ,i.IUNITS UM
    ,i.IPRCCD PClass
    ,i.ICSTCD CClass
    ,i.IPACCD Pack
    ,CASE
        WHEN (i.IPRCCD = '') THEN
            i.ILIST
        ELSE /* i.IPRCCD is not empty, so */
            /*Use p.$LIST if not null. Otherwise, use i.ILIST*/
            COALESCE(p.$LIST, i.ILIST)
    END AS PRICE
FROM DB.ITEM i
    ,DB.PRICE p
WHERE
    (i.IMFGR = '" & man & "')
    AND (
        i.IPRCCD = ''
        OR p.$PRCCD = i.IPRCCD
    )
ORDER BY i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT
```

Comment: Mustaccio beat me to it. Guess that's what happens when I get pulled away and don't refresh when I come back.